# Connect button disabled in Azure

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, docker

Trying to move away from the Scalable Wordpress option in Azure for hosting a Wordpress Multisite setup as having to use ClearDB for the database is just proving too slow or too costly.

Just launched Wordpress + mySQL virtual machine using Docker on Azure as it looked like a better option for the scale I'm looking at. One click and the normal Wordpress is all working fine. Need to edit the wp-config file and can't get access to remote desktop. The connect button is greyed out so I can't rdp in. Been trying to figure it out for a few days now but can't seem to find the right solution.

Any pointers on what I need to look at or next steps really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to RDP, first create an endpoint. To do so, go to endpoint tab of VM and then click on add endpoint. Select appropriate endpoint in your case "REMOTE DESKTOP". It will take few seconds to update the VM. After that connect button will surely become clickable for you.

For reference LINK-
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks for the response! Trouble is I'm using the new Portal and my virtual machine doesn't show up in the old manage.windowsazure.com interface only in portal.azure.com. Have had a look for the endpoint option but it only seems to show up in what's classed as virtual machine (classic).

Answer (score 0):

As there is a note on the introduction page of WordPress +MySQL template:

> NOTE: By default, this deployment doesn't enable remote client connections to the Docker Engine. You can enable remote access while creating the virtual machine in Settings > Docker > Engine.

Like the figure.
[image]

After created, we can find inbound rules in the resource group which your VM in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there any options to enable remote access after creating the virtual machine? Or only on setup?

Comment: What's your remote access referring for? By default, Azure VMs have enabled port 22 when finishing creating for `ssh` remote. And if you want remote to a desktop on Linux VMs, we have to install desktop environment on them first. You can refer http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm.aspx